# Web service unit testing

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, testing, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS web services (client and exposed services), is there any API to test these web services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- test the services out of their "web-service" context.
- Use [WSUnit](https://github.com/lapistano/wsunit) to test consumers.
- take a look at  [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/ws-dw-ws-soa-autotest2.html)

Unit tests are meant to test units of code. They should test business logic, and not infrastructure. So this is not exactly "unit-testing" if you want to test the services within the web-service context.

Comment: So what would you call a test that fires up the service and tests it via the endpoint? :) Also the wsunit link is a 404?

Comment: more broadly - "integration test", probably. I fixed the link

Answer (score 7):

JAX-WS web services are annotated POJOs so you can **unit test** them (in isolation) using a regular unit testing framework (JUnit, TestNG) and Mocks.

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain? Downvoting this answer is a pure joke (showing that you have no clue about what unit testing means BTW).

Comment: Not exactly though. They are _annotated_ which means they aren't just Plain Java Objects in that respect. They have additional metadata directly attached to them which changes their behavior. Something that cannot be capture by testing them directly as plain objects. There are things to test such as Security constraints, transaction interactions, asynchronous invocations, etc. All of which is part of the issue of mixing the business logic with the exposure of a web service.

Answer (score 4):

For functional testing - you can use tools like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) (but I don't recommend this option because tests created with this tool are really hard to maintain). Other option (recommended) is using JUnit tests in which you create the service + client and exercise service methods. In our project we use Apache [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and it works very well. It also supports JAX-WS.

For unit testing - "regular" JUnit, since generated service is Plain Java Object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jersey to test end points: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/test-framework.html